# Climate / weather generation on 3d hex map

Tags: tilemap, procedural-generation, maps, heightmap

I am working on 3d hex map game. I am aiming to dynamical generate map (as new players joins). To make the map realistic I am looking for some climate/weather models which possibly I could use so that the generated terrain / game environment remains realistic.

Currently I am not having any system implemented to generate hex map. I was thinking of using height map but I am looking for ways to connect with it also such variables as aridity, temperature so that it is as realistic as possible. I may not exclude that in future I will want players to be able to modify the climate (e.g. via spells) and thus, the map generation mechanism should work not only during map generation but also should be able to calculate further changes in environment caused by players. It would be the best if given model would be able to be used also to calculate impact of climate and weather on crops, speed of troops and so on.

Would you be so kind and advise on any ready climate generation/administration solutions? I am looking for something quite complex to be from one hand maximally realistic and from the other  in further able to generate game variables such as current weather information.

Comment: What should it include? Mountains(snow), deserts, water, region-specific weather,...?

Comment: I have seen several topics here relating to making map based on given list of terrain titles. However, I am looking for something more complex to be able to generate climate/weather condition for each piece of map e.g. arid, temperature and the generate e.g. crops growth for given title.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what concrete problem you're having? In what ways is your current model insufficient?

Comment: @Anko: The problem is that I don't have and model implemented and can't find any.